# select tab JQuery and unselect

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, tabs

I'll try to be as posible specific with my problem:

When i am in my web page, i have already selected one tab, so i'm trying to validate that the user doesn't change from one tab if my actual tab it is not validated or processed (in example a form capture). So in the event of the click of the other tabs i'm inserting the following code:

```
$("#aTab0").click(function() {
    if(!validation){
        var $tabs=$(".tabs").tabs(); 
        $tabs.tabs('select', 0);
        return;
    }               
});
```

And it's ok, it changes again to the actual tab BUT the style of the TAB clicked has changed..  i want it to remain un-clicked..

An idea of what i want is if i could stop the event of the other(s) tab being clicked..

PLEASE HELP! I need somebody.. =P

THANKS in advance!

Comment: Also, if you're using jQuery, you can try  `event.stopPropagation()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "return;" to "return false;", that should do it. Returning "false" in an event handling function should stop the event from processing.

Comment: More specifically, `return false` is equivalent to `event.stopImmediatePropogation()` and `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: It doesnt work yet, if i return to the actual TAB, the style of the Tab clicked it doesn't return to un-selected...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".tabs").tabs("option", "selected", 0);
```